# Android Socket Lockup with PC - PC thinks we're still connected, Android doesn't

Tags: android, tcp

We're using Android devices as remote controls for an industrial process controlled by a PC.

Sometimes the connection may be broken unexpectedly - the battery dies, the Android device goes out of range, network problems, wireless-access-point reset, the Android gets restarted, etc.  In these circumstances the PC may not "know" it's been disconnected because it never gets a FIN.

So when I'm restarting things on the Android side, and I'm initializing the socket I do a

```
sock = new Socket(ipAddress, portNumber);
```

and on a network sniffer (Wireshark) I can see the Android sends a SYN.   But because the PC doesn't know it was disconnected, i.e., it thinks it's still connected from before, it sends RST, ACK.     This results in the Android Socket constructor returning null.

What I need to do is send a FIN, not a SYN, to the PC.  But I thought a SYN has to be the first packet in the handshaking (I'm **not** a network expert).  Or alternatively, to not start with a SYN, so I can just start re-using the connection as though nothing happened. Is there any way to do that?   How do I break this deadlock from the Android side?   (I have no control over what the PC does)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fundamental consequence of the way the TCP handshaking scheme works.  It's not something you can fix from the remote end (without breaking the rules of TCP), but rather something where each end has to decide for itself how it will handle things.

On the server side you address it with the reuse setting on the server socket, and configuring timeouts and possibly a limit on the number of close-wait sockets in the operating system.

On the client side you need to decide at what point you will give up on the existence of the other end and start over.  This likely means you will have to modify the behavior of the PC as it seems that the current client program was written without logic to handle the expectable case of loss of network connectivity.

Comment: When you say "client" are you referring to the Android or the PC?  (I think of the client as the Android, and the PC as the server)   Are you saying that there's nothing I can do on the Android side about this lockup?

Comment: The server is whoever maintains the listening socket, the client is whoever connects to it.  Yes, I'm saying that you will have to fix the problem on whichever side is experiencing it.  It sounds like you've been asked to interact with a program written by someone who did not yet have the experience to realize the range of conditions which it must handle on the wired Internet, let alone mobile devices.

Comment: The PC is the listener.   I was confused because you said " the current client program was written without logic to handle the expectable case of loss of network connectivity"   I'm still not sure what you mean by "whichever side is experiencing it"  - it's the Android (the client) that's experiencing the RST's but it's unclear what can be done from the Android side.

Comment: The lockup issue will have to be fixed on whichever side is experiencing it.  If the PC is acting as the server, you can try substituting netcat (get a version built with listening support) for the current program, and see if you can successfully reconnect to that.  It's archaic source, but it does show how to setup a listening socket to which one can reconnect after network loss, however there is also operating system configuration required if these events are going to be frequent.

Comment: "The lockup issue will have to be fixed on whichever side is experiencing it."  I still can't parse what you mean by "experiencing it".  The PC "experiences" the SYN, the Android "experiences" the RST, the result is a mutual deadlock.     My original question is: is there anything that can be dome on the Android side?

Comment: Whichever program is unable to procede will have to be modified so that it can do so **without any cooperation from the other end**.  Quite possibly that means you must make changes to both programs - they need to work no matter what the other end does to them.

Comment: Chris, it's very confusing for anyone else reading this thread if you keep editing your comments after you make them because then my responses to your first drafts are out of sync.

Comment: As I said, originally, I have no control over what's on the PC.   My question is whether there's anything I can do on the Android side.

Comment: You will have to get control over what happens on the PC, or dump that side of the problem back on the authors of the broken software running there.